# Update qty of a product using product id in magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to update a product `qty` using `product_id`, I am struggling to frame query in magento. I have searched in google but i did not get clear solution.

My query is:

```
update table_name set qty="54" where product_id="545";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the SQL queries, try the magento way to update product qty like this :

```
$productId = '545';
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
if ($stockItem->getId() > 0 and $stockItem->getManageStock()) {
    $qty = 100;
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
    $stockItem->save();
}
```

Comment: It is working, Thank you so much for helping.. @Manashvi birla.